# ibatis.net - isqlmapper.BeforeQuery missing in 1.6.1

Tags: sql, ibatis.net

We are trying to upgrade to **iBatis.Net DataMapper 1.6.1** (from **1.5.1**). I am getting an error on this line:

```
( ( SqlMapDaoSession ) daoManager.GetDaoSession() ).SqlMap.BeforeQuery += new BeforeQueryDelegate ( SqlMap_BeforeQuery );
```

I cannot even find a reference to this `BeforeQuery` event anywhere. 0 matches on Google!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I looked in the iBatis 1.5.1 source and there is no `BeforeQuery` event on the `SqlMap` class, or anywhere in the project for that matter. You must have a modified version.  What does your code do in the `SqlMap_BeforeQuery` delegate?

Comment: Very interesting! This was wired by a developer no longer with the company. He must have modified the iBatis code... We use that event handler to modify the sql statement in the IDbCommand before it is run. Any ideas how (in the unmodified code) that we can do the same?

Thank you!